# Change READ TIMEOUT for a batch HTTP Request on using Google API Client Library for Java

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am making batch requests for adding members to groups. For this I am using OAuth2.0 and obtaining the object of class type Credential.When executed, the batch.execute() throws a

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException : Read timed out
```

To change the timeout limit, this is the solution I found :
[GoogleApps client giving SocketTimeOutException only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843439/googleapps-client-giving-sockettimeoutexception-only)

But I am not able to change the timeout of the Credential object I am creating.

```
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

NOTE : Credential implements HttpRequestInitializer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Found this after a long time! There is a separate HttpRequestInitializer object for a batch HTTP and an atomic HTTP request to Google. I had earlier changed the HttpRequestInitializer object of the atomic requests (expecting the same to have affect on batch requests) as below:

```
new Directory.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
                credential.initialize(httpRequest);
                httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
                httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3);  // 3 minutes read timeout
                System.out.println("Hello"); // Just to track when a http request is made.

            }
        }).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

This resulted in the set read timeout for atomic requests. The batch request, sent using `batch.execute()` still had the default read timeout.
To change the same for the batch requests, I changed this in my `BatchRequest` intializaiton :

```
BatchRequest batch = service.batch(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                    credential.initialize(request);
                    request.setConnectTimeout(10 * 60000);
                    request.setReadTimeout(10 * 60000);
                    System.out.println(request.getReadTimeout() + 2); //Just to track when a batch http request is made.
                }
            });
```

Comment: The timeout values should be in milliseconds.